# Returning two values as function to two different variables in php

Tags: php, function

```
function foo($a)
{
    $b = ...;
    $c = ...;
    return (both b and c);
}
```

and so I could get `$b` value to `$first` and `$c` value to `$second`

I know you can return more than 1 variable by `return array($b,$c)` but then it should be `$var[0]` and `$var[1]` and then I need to type `$first = $var[0]` and `$second = $var[1]` and so I'm creating more useless variables

So is it possible to do so without array?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fundamentally, functions only have one return value.  You could return a class with member variables `first` and `second`, or an associative array with keys `"first"` and `"second"`, but you'll still only be returning a single object.<sup>*</sup>

Alternatively, you could references to `$first` and `$second` into your function:

```
function foo($a, &$b, &$c)
{
    $b = ...;
    $c = ...;
}

foo(42, $first, $second);
```

I'm not a big fan of this approach, though, because it's not immediately clear from the call-site that `$first` and `$second` are going to be modified.

<sub>* Note that if you return an array, you can always use the short-hand `list($first,$second) = foo(42);`.</sub>

Answer (score 2):

No, it can't.

But you can still return an array from function, but use "list" to accept the result for convenient:

```
list ($first, $second) = foo ($a);
```

Answer (score 1):

No, you cannot to that. Function returns only one result.

What you can do, if possible in you case, is pass a variable by reference.

```
function foo($a, &$b, &$c){
 $b = ...;
 $c = ...;
}
```

The following will make changes to $b and $c visible outside of the function scope.

Answer (score 0):

The only alternative to avoid returning an array is to return an object, or serialized data, but you don't "win" something from that.